# Would like to plot triangles while specifying color of vertices

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

In the following code, trying to specify that the points are red?  Why not all of them are red?  Also, is it possible to combine a and b into one plot?

```
n = 3;
\[Theta] = (2 \[Pi] Range[0, n])/n;
points = Transpose@{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}; k = Range[3];
p = Outer[Times, k, points]; 
a = ListLinePlot[p, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   AspectRatio -> 2/Sqrt[3], PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All];
b = ListPlot[p, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}];
Show[a, b]
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP**

We should `Flatten` the data about `b` and set the `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to use the original scaling.

```
n = 3;
θ = (2 π Range[0, n])/n;
points = Transpose@{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]};
k = Range[3];
p = Outer[Times, k, points]; a = 
 ListLinePlot[p, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> All];
b = ListPlot[Flatten[p, 1], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}];
Show[a, b, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

**Another way**

`RegularPolygon` or `CirclePoints` is convenient.

```
Graphics[{Table[
   HighlightMesh[
    TransformedRegion[RegularPolygon[r, 3], 
     RotationTransform[3 π/2]], {Style[
      0, {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], Style[1, Blue], 
     Style[2, None]}], {r, {1, 2, 3}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you!